video not played in flutter
I want to play video in flutter. this is my source code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:second_project/core/api_client.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class MyProfileScreenUtility_MyPostVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postVideo;

  const MyProfileScreenUtility_MyPostVideo({
    super.key,
    required this.postVideo,
  });

  @override
  State<MyProfileScreenUtility_MyPostVideo> createState() =>
      _MyProfileScreenUtility_MyPostVideoState();
}

class _MyProfileScreenUtility_MyPostVideoState
    extends State<MyProfileScreenUtility_MyPostVideo> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    String url = (ApiClient.baseUrl + widget.postVideo).replaceAll("\\", "/");
    //String url =
    //'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4';    
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    //_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/Videos/butterfly.mp4");

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    //_controller.setLooping(true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                      _controller.pause();
                    } else {
                      _controller.play();
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


But video not play and black screen displayed. I used video_player package.
The following screenshot shows that the video URL is correctly generated in my source code:
video url
a sample generated video url in program debug = http://amiini.ir/api/Uploads/UploadedFiles/164e6f65-bca6-4424-b660-89e243a36648.mp4
In documents of video_player package has been used video https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4 as demo. so i used this url and then video played. also i uploaded exactly the same video on my server but video not play and black screen displayed.
Please help me.

The problem is Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted,
we can  find the solution in the official android documentation
that says:
This error will occur if your app requests cleartext HTTP traffic (that is, http:// rather than https://) when its Network Security Configuration does not permit it. If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or higher, cleartext HTTP traffic is disabled by the default configuration.
......you can simply add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application element of your app's AndroidManifest.xml.
other way is just get a ssl cert for your host and start using HTTPS

My Problem resolved. thanks @ildeberto-vasconcelos

how did you fixed? buddy @programmer1360
it's important to flag how you fixed because others devs are looking for solutions also

I add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application element of app's AndroidManifest.xml.

perfect
so mark the answer as correct, so that others can find it quickly
